Separating one mysql row into n different ones
My company's client has a table to store inventory data, this inventory separates products using a column called product_code, and it has another column called Qtd that stores how many of the same products are in stock. What I need help with is that I need to separate this one row of products into n different rows, with n being the value stored in Qtd. Example:
Original:



row
product_code
Qtd




1
111
15



New:



row
product_code
Qtd




1
111
1


2
111
1


3
111
1


...
...
...


14
111
1


15
111
1



I need to create this new rows because they're trying to introduce a new column that represents the serial number of the products, that is unique and I'm unable to use joins because this serial number is stored in a different database. We have a way to assign a serial number to a product based on its product code, but only the first serial number is being paired correctly, and separating this single row into different rows would solve this particular problem in an practical way, if it's possible of course.
We've tried doing this using our software, but it ended with only the first serial number being assigned to a row and all the others being left unused. We're hoping that this try would separate the data into different rows.

Please read this guide on how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I don't think there's anything built into MySQL that will do this. You can do it in a stored procedure, or in an application programming language.

you'd use a cte to generate the rows and insert them into a new table, then rename the new table to the old

I have some thoughts on how this might work, but I need to know version of MySQL? Or if you're at least up to version 8, instead of the ancient 5.7? And is there a reasonable max value for Qtd we can assume?

also, it helps us answer your question if you don't keep your table name a secret :)

@JoelCoehoorn The table name is fatopedido, and we use MySQL version 8.0.36. Most of the time the values for Qtd are not going to be more than 20/25 but it's not a rule.

What is the highest value for qtd in the table, and what are the chances you'll get data higher than this? Is there growth over time?

@JoelCoehoorn The highest value for qtd is 1110, while the average is 3.5. Its pretty common for a select few products to have a high Qtd but they do not grow over time. Because the company has a predictable demand for most itens in inventory they keep very low amounts of any single items at any given time, and it'll not pass the 5000 mark, even for this one product, at any given time.

Ideally you do this on the entire table, while nothing else is changing it.  If you need to support concurrent activity, it is a lot more complicated.
Start by preparing making a new table to get the new rows:
create table new_inventory like inventory;
rename table inventory to old_inventory, new_inventory to inventory;

Then insert the split rows using a recursive cte to generate them:
insert into inventory (product_code, Qtd)
with recursive generate_rows as (
  select product_code, Qtd from old_inventory
  union all
  select product_code, Qtd-1 from generate_rows where Qtd > 1
)
select product_code, 1 Qtd from generate_rows;


@Roemer ? no, they want all the Qtd to be 1.  removing the 1 would make them 15, 14, 13, 12 ... 1

You are right, I am sorry. I tried an extremely similar example based on this one but where the 1 just didn't make sense. I will remove my comment.

@Roemer with some modifications I think this could work, thanks. We'll try and come back to you with the results.

It worked better then expected, as we'd end up with all the end qtd being 1 we can just manually set them after making sure the process worked. As this is a one time adjustment for the data we already had in the DB and it shouldn't be needed for the future we got what we needed.
